# VBS - Get Default Printer

Tags: vbscript, printing

Using the Wscript.Network object shown below, is there an easy way to retrieve the default printer on a machine?  I know how to set the default printer, but I'm looking to get the current default printer name.  I have a mixture of Windows 2000, XP, and 7 clients and don't want to use WMI for that reason.

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
Set objLocalPrinters = objNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections
```

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use WMI?

Comment: I was told that some of the functions within the script may not be compatiable with Windows 2000 machines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections` collection doesn't provide any information about the default printer. You can try retrieving the default printer name from the registry instead, though I'm not sure if it's reliable:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strValue = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device"
strPrinter = oShell.RegRead(strValue)
strPrinter = Split(strPrinter, ",")(0)
WScript.Echo strPrinter
```

As for WMI, it's true that some WMI classes and class members aren't available on older Windows versions. For example, the [`Win32_Printer.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363.aspx) property that indicates whether the printer is the default one, doesn't exist on Windows 2000/NT. Nevertheless, there's a simple workaround for finding the default printer on those Windows versions, which consists in checking for the `PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULT` attribute in each printer's `Attribute` bitmask:

```
Const ATTR_DEFAULT = 4
strComputer = "."

Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colPrinters = oWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer")

For Each oPrinter in colPrinters
    If oPrinter.Attributes And ATTR_DEFAULT Then 
        Wscript.Echo oPrinter.ShareName
    End If
Next
```

This code works on later Windows versions as well.

For details, check out this *Hey, Scripting Guy!* article: [Is There Any Way to Determine the Default Printer On a Computer?](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/11/17/hey-scripting-guy-is-there-any-way-to-determine-the-default-printer-on-a-computer.aspx)

Comment: I saw a post similar to this as well, but it doesn't seem to be relevant to Windows 7.

Comment: For the WMI wxample, if the default printer is local then you may need to use  "Wscript.Echo oPrinter.Name" to get the name as it won't necessarily be shared.

Answer (score 2):

From ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhds6k80(VS.85).aspx)):

The EnumPrinterConnections method returns a collection. This collection is an array that associates pairs of items — network printer local names and their associated UNC names. Even-numbered items in the collection represent printer ports. Odd-numbered items represent the networked printer UNC names. The first item in the collection is at index zero (0).

So there is little chance to get the default printer from this collection. Sorry

Greetz,
GHad

Answer (score -1):

for MS ACCESS oPrinter.ShareName is null but oPrinter.Caption works well!

```
Dim strComputer As String
Dim oWMI As Object
Dim colPrinters
Dim oPrinter
Const ATTR_DEFAULT = 4
strComputer = "."

Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colPrinters = oWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer")

For Each oPrinter In colPrinters
    If oPrinter.Attributes And ATTR_DEFAULT Then
        Debug.Print oPrinter.Caption
    End If
Next
```